# Summer 22: Deleting Public Group doesn't delete Shares in Apex Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, apex-managed-sharing

I have a test that was working fine for 2 years, unchanged, which is now failing post Summer 22. Ultimately, it deletes a Public Group and the assertion tests that any associated AccountShares are also deleted.

I've debugged and the Group is in fact being deleted (this particular DML occurs in a @future method to avoid a Mixed DML exception, but in the test context, it executes synchronously). However, it appears the `Test.stopTest();` method is not executing the asynchronous removal of obsolete shares, as specified [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_delete_obsolete_shares.htm&type=5).

Should I assume this is related to the [Summer 22 test resource updates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_parallel_apex_test_resources.htm&type=5&release=238)? Or perhaps this is a bug? I haven't and likely won't submit a support case because we don't have Premier and they'll likely ignore anything I submit that involves code.

Test Code (deletes a custom object "List", which has a corresponding Public Group, which gets deleted via trigger):

```
List<AccountShare> testShares = [SELECT UserOrGroupId, AccountId
                                 FROM AccountShare
                                 WHERE UserOrGroupId = :td.testGroup.Id
                                 AND AccountId = :td.testAccount.Id];

System.assertEquals(1, testShares.size(), 'Expected 1 AccountShare to exist.');

Test.startTest();
delete td.testList;
Test.stopTest();

testShares = [SELECT UserOrGroupId, AccountId
              FROM AccountShare
              WHERE UserOrGroupId = :td.testGroup.Id
              AND AccountId = :td.testAccount.Id];

System.assertEquals(0, testShares.size(), 'Expected no AccountShares to exist.');
```

Relevant trigger code that deletes the Public Group, which I've confirmed is executing & is deleting the Public Group:

```
@Future
private static void deletePublicGroupsFuture(Set<String> publicGroupNames) {
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE DeveloperName IN :publicGroupNames];
}
```

Comment: I've asked people who might know or can find out for us.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if this had anything to do with the "fairer use" change for test execution (which has caused a minimum of 50% longer test execution times for us). I would suspect they refactored the code so the share deletion is performed asynchronously. Since the group deletion is in a future (so async) and `Test.stopTest` only synchronizes on asyncs directly queued after the preceding `Test.startTest`, I would guess the deletion happens after your test completes. You might like to use some anonymous apex to validate this change, to see if I'm right or it's a bug...

Comment: This would not have anything to do with the Apex release note about test resources. I've asked a few folks in the sharing area if they have any thoughts about this. Will report back.

Comment: @ca_peterson thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This looks to stem from a change made to how obsolete sharing records are handled to make this kind of cleanup of no-op (since the group is deleted, nobody is actually in it, so the share records don't *do* anything in practice).

See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_delete_obsolete_shares.htm&type=5 for the help that describes the behavior where this kind of share would be deleted async now.

IMHO this is a good change, since it makes sharing changes much faster, as this kind of cascading delete could be extremely slow at scale when done sync - but it is certainly a change.

I just found out that this was enabled more widely this release - looking for a doc reference to share about that.

Comment: Thanks! So is this now expected behavior in the test context?